# Assigning to submatrices in python

Tags: matlab, numpy

Yes, this question has been asked many times, but I think there's one point that makes this different.

When I want to assign a small numpy array to a section in a matrix, I do,

```
K[0:2, 0:2] = M;   # Eqn 1
```

but the following does not work

```
K[range(0,2), range(0,2)] = M;  # Eqn 2
```

where M is a 2X2 matrix and K is a larger one.

My end application is for assigning to specific sections of the matrix K, whose row indices and column indices are stored in `rows` and `cols` respectively, which are sets. I want to do something like,

```
K[rows,cols] = M;  # Eqn 3
```

Is this possible in python? It's a really easy thing to do with matlab.